# D3.js combining filtering by column value and using brush for zooming

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, visualization

I am new to D3.js and have been following examples on this website:

https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/line.html

I am specifically trying to include a dropdown to filter by a column value and also include a brush for zooming.

The data I am using is simply country, date and covid_cases and I am trying to have an initial monthly line chart that can be zoomed in, while also having the ability to filter by country.

I have taken the code directly from these examples:

- https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_brushZoom.html
- https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/line_filter.html

I successfully altered them to fit my data, but am unable to combine them to enable both interactions.

Does anyone have any advice on how I might do this?

Comment: Please include your code on the question rather than linking to outside sources. For more info please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask